# How to read request in an Interceptor in Spring

Tags: spring, interceptor

I can't use getReader() because in some other class getReader() is already used and the logic can't be changed.
How can I read it from interceptor? 
I need to persist request, response and status from interceptor. So for this, I need to access request and response.

Trying to call service from preHandle()

Comment: isnt the HttpServletRequest available in the preHandle() method ?

Comment: that is available. The signature of method is that is available. The signature of method is  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {}

Comment: so what is your question then? dont you have the request right there?

Comment: public static String getRequestData(final HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
     String payload = null;
     ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
     if (wrapper != null) {
         byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
         if (buf.length > 0) {
             payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
         }
     }return payload;} Getting empty payload here

Comment: request is there. If I access request body through this piece of code, I am able to access it request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())); But I cant use getReader() with reference to the request in this class. Need some other alternative to do that

Comment: this is hard to read. Please re-formulate your question with code